# Vue 3 + TypeScript: Objects returned from setup() using the JS spread operator throw an error in vscode

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, auth0, vue-composition-api

I have a simple [Vue 3 + TypeScript repo](https://github.com/BenJackGill/auth0-vue3) where I am trying to integrate an Auth0 plugin.

It displays the stringified `user` object on the frontend, and it works as expected.

But Visual Studio Code is showing a TypeScript error `Cannot find name 'user'. ts(2304)` because it cannot see the object `user` when returned inside an `...auth` spread operator.

I'm not sure why it is doing that, or how to resolve it.

This is the code for the Auth0 plugin. In a nutshell, it is using `app.provide("Auth", authPlugin);` to provide access to a bunch of stuff, including a `user` object:

```
import createAuth0Client, {
  Auth0Client,
  GetIdTokenClaimsOptions,
  GetTokenSilentlyOptions,
  GetTokenWithPopupOptions,
  LogoutOptions,
  RedirectLoginOptions,
  User,
} from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";
import { App, Plugin, computed, reactive, watchEffect } from "vue";
import { NavigationGuardWithThis } from "vue-router";

let client: Auth0Client;

interface Auth0PluginState {
  loading: boolean;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  user: User | undefined;
  popupOpen: boolean;
  error: any;
}

const state = reactive<Auth0PluginState>({
  loading: true,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  popupOpen: false,
  error: null,
});

async function handleRedirectCallback() {
  state.loading = true;

  try {
    await client.handleRedirectCallback();
    state.user = await client.getUser();
    state.isAuthenticated = true;
  } catch (e) {
    state.error = e;
  } finally {
    state.loading = false;
  }
}

function loginWithRedirect(o: RedirectLoginOptions) {
  return client.loginWithRedirect(o);
}

function getIdTokenClaims(o: GetIdTokenClaimsOptions) {
  return client.getIdTokenClaims(o);
}

function getTokenSilently(o: GetTokenSilentlyOptions) {
  return client.getTokenSilently(o);
}

function getTokenWithPopup(o: GetTokenWithPopupOptions) {
  return client.getTokenWithPopup(o);
}

function logout(o: LogoutOptions) {
  return client.logout(o);
}

const authPlugin = {
  isAuthenticated: computed(() => state.isAuthenticated),
  loading: computed(() => state.loading),
  user: computed(() => state.user),
  getIdTokenClaims,
  getTokenSilently,
  getTokenWithPopup,
  handleRedirectCallback,
  loginWithRedirect,
  logout,
};

const routeGuard: NavigationGuardWithThis<undefined> = (
  to: any,
  from: any,
  next: any
) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, loading, loginWithRedirect } = authPlugin;

  const verify = async () => {
    // If the user is authenticated, continue with the route
    if (isAuthenticated.value) {
      return next();
    }

    // Otherwise, log in
    await loginWithRedirect({ appState: { targetUrl: to.fullPath } });
  };

  // If loading has already finished, check our auth state using `fn()`
  if (!loading.value) {
    return verify();
  }

  // Watch for the loading property to change before we check isAuthenticated
  watchEffect(() => {
    if (!loading.value) {
      return verify();
    }
  });
};

interface Auth0PluginOptions {
  domain: string;
  clientId: string;
  audience: string;
  redirectUri: string;

  onRedirectCallback(appState: any): void;
}

async function init(options: Auth0PluginOptions): Promise<Plugin> {
  client = await createAuth0Client({
    // domain: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    // client_id: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_KEY,
    domain: options.domain,
    client_id: options.clientId,
    audience: options.audience,
    redirect_uri: options.redirectUri,
  });

  try {
    // If the user is returning to the app after authentication
    if (
      window.location.search.includes("code=") &&
      window.location.search.includes("state=")
    ) {
      // handle the redirect and retrieve tokens
      const { appState } = await client.handleRedirectCallback();

      // Notify subscribers that the redirect callback has happened, passing the appState
      // (useful for retrieving any pre-authentication state)
      options.onRedirectCallback(appState);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    state.error = e;
  } finally {
    // Initialize our internal authentication state
    state.isAuthenticated = await client.isAuthenticated();
    state.user = await client.getUser();
    state.loading = false;
  }

  return {
    install: (app: App) => {
      app.provide("Auth", authPlugin);
    },
  };
}

interface Auth0Plugin {
  init(options: Auth0PluginOptions): Promise<Plugin>;
  routeGuard: NavigationGuardWithThis<undefined>;
}

export const Auth0: Auth0Plugin = {
  init,
  routeGuard,
};
```

Here in my `Profile.vue` page I am injecting the Auth0 plugin using `const auth = inject<Auth0Client>("Auth")!;` and returning all of its content from `setup()` using the `...auth` spread operator. This includes the `user` object which is now available to use in the template.

All of this is working on the front end. It displays the stringified `user` object as expected.

But vscode is throwing an `Cannot find name 'user'. ts(2304)` error because the `user` object is not explicitly returned from `setup()`.

It seems like it doesn't know that the `...auth` spread operator has the `user` object inside `auth`:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is a profile page, only logged in users can see it.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    {{ JSON.stringify(user, null, 2) }} <!-- ERROR: Cannot find name 'user'.ts(2304) -->
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Auth0Client } from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";
import { inject } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Profile",
  setup() {
    const auth = inject<Auth0Client>("Auth")!;
    return {
      ...auth,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I have tried to solve this problem by explicitly returning a `user` object as shown below, but it breaks the functionality. The stringified `user` object is no longer displays on the front end:

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is a profile page, only logged in users can see it.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    {{ JSON.stringify(auth_user, null, 2) }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Auth0Client } from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";
import { inject } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Profile",
  setup() {
    const auth = inject<Auth0Client>("Auth")!;
    const auth_user = auth.getUser(); // This does not work
    //const auth_user = auth.user; // This variation also doesn't work
    return {
      auth_user,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Can anyone figure out what is going on here and how to solve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. The [`Auth0Client` class](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/3ca3edd/src/Auth0Client.ts#L190) has no `user` field, so returning `{ ...auth }` from `setup()` would not create a `user` property. But this isn't the type you want, as we see in the next point.

```js
export default class Auth0Client {
  private options;
  private transactionManager;
  private cacheManager;
  private customOptions;
  private domainUrl;
  private tokenIssuer;
  private defaultScope;
  private scope;
  private cookieStorage;
  private sessionCheckExpiryDays;
  private orgHintCookieName;
  private isAuthenticatedCookieName;
  private nowProvider;
  cacheLocation: CacheLocation;
  private worker;
  constructor(options: Auth0ClientOptions);
  private _url;
  private _getParams;
  private _authorizeUrl;
  private _verifyIdToken;
  private _parseNumber;
  private _processOrgIdHint;
  buildAuthorizeUrl(options?: RedirectLoginOptions): Promise<string>;
  loginWithPopup(options?: PopupLoginOptions, config?: PopupConfigOptions): Promise<void>;
  getUser<TUser extends User>(options?: GetUserOptions): Promise<TUser | undefined>;
  getIdTokenClaims(options?: GetIdTokenClaimsOptions): Promise<IdToken>;
  loginWithRedirect(options?: RedirectLoginOptions): Promise<void>;
  handleRedirectCallback(url?: string): Promise<RedirectLoginResult>;
  checkSession(options?: GetTokenSilentlyOptions): Promise<void>;
  getTokenSilently(options: GetTokenSilentlyOptions & {
      detailedResponse: true;
  }): Promise<GetTokenSilentlyVerboseResponse>;
  getTokenSilently(options?: GetTokenSilentlyOptions): Promise<string>;
  private _getTokenSilently;
  getTokenWithPopup(options?: GetTokenWithPopupOptions, config?: PopupConfigOptions): Promise<string>;
  isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean>;
  buildLogoutUrl(options?: LogoutUrlOptions): string;
  logout(options?: LogoutOptions): Promise<void> | void;
  private _getTokenFromIFrame;
  private _getTokenUsingRefreshToken;
  private _getEntryFromCache;
}
```

2. While the `Auth` object is `inject`ed as an `Auth0Client`, the [actual object `provide`d in `@/auth/index.ts`](https://github.com/BenJackGill/auth0-vue3/blob/d35e266/src/auth/index.ts#L65-L75) has a type that does not overlap with `Auth0Client`. The actual type should be exported so that components that `inject` the `Auth` object could type the reference:

```js
const authPlugin = {
  isAuthenticated: computed(() => state.isAuthenticated),
  loading: computed(() => state.loading),
  user: computed(() => state.user),
  getIdTokenClaims,
  getTokenSilently,
  getTokenWithPopup,
  handleRedirectCallback,
  loginWithRedirect,
  logout,
};

export type ProvidedAuthPlugin = typeof authPlugin; 
⋮
app.provide("Auth", authPlugin);
```

3. To [enable TypeScript support in a component](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components) (including within the `<template>`), the component definition should be declared with `defineComponent`:

```js
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  ⋮
});
```

4. And the `Auth` object's type should be used in the component when `inject`ing it:

```js
import type { ProvidedAuthPlugin } from "@/auth"; 
import { inject, defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Profile",
  setup() {                              
    const auth = inject("Auth") as ProvidedAuthPlugin;
    return {
      ...auth,
    };
  },
});
```

[GitHub PR](https://github.com/BenJackGill/auth0-vue3/pull/1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok for what I understand (I'm not an expert with composition API).

Here for instance in `setup()`, the `return` statement should provide you what you will have available inside the `<template>`.

let's say you want to use user here

```html
 <div class="row">
    {{ JSON.stringify(user, null, 2) }} <!-- ERROR: Cannot find name 'user'.ts(2304) -->
  </div>
```

Basically it doesn't find any kind of `user` data. let's try adding it in the `return` statement of `setup()`

#### Try this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is a profile page, only logged in users can see it.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    {{ JSON.stringify(user, null, 2) }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { inject, ref } from 'vue'
import { Auth0Client, User } from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js'

export default {
  name: 'Profile',
  setup() {
    /* Added for you this 2 lines, one for getting types of auth
       I think the other one is reactive */
    const auth = inject('Auth') as Auth0Client
    const user = ref<User | undefined>(undefined)

    auth.getUser().then((authuser) => (user.value = authuser))
    return {
      ...auth, // Check this one, I don't see it being used in <template>
      user // This one should be available in <template> now
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Hopefully it works... Also I'm not a big fan of composition API if for whatever reason you are just learning Vue use the default API, it's a lot easier to learn and use :).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this has broken the display of `user` on the profile page. I think it's made it non-reactive somehow.

Comment: I think in the original the spread operator on `...auth` was helping to return `user` which was inside `auth`. I'm still learning about spread operators so I could be wrong, but I think that is why it worked before.

Comment: Side effects go to onMounted, it's a bad practice to put them directly to setup. Or they could be awaited in setup, but this forces it to be used with suspense.

Comment: @EstusFlask could you elaborate more with an answer? I don't fully understand

Comment: You need to put `auth.getUser()` inside onMounted, or await for it https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/suspense.html#introduction if you want the component to not render without data.